# How to Convert 2 Arrays to JSON using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following 2 integer arrays along with a denied reason:

```
var approvedItems = [2051, 2567];
    var deniedItems = [2053, 2569];
string deniedReason = "Naughty";
```

I want to create the following JSON:

```
{
    "Responses": [{
        "ResponseID": 2051,
        "IsApprove": true
    },
    {
        "ResponseID": 2567,
        "IsApprove": true
    },
    {
        "ResponseID": 2053,
        "IsApprove": false
    },
    {
        "ResponseID": 2569,
        "IsApprove": false
    }],
    "Reason": "Naughty"
}
```

How can I do that using angular/javascript?

Comment: That does not look like JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May Help

```
var approvedItems = [2051, 2567];
var deniedItems = [2053, 2569];
var deniedReason = "Naughty";

var resResponse = {};
var responses = [];
if(approvedItems.length || deniedItems.length) {

    for(var ind =0; ind < approvedItems.length; ind++) {
        var response = {
            "ResponseID": approvedItems[ind],
            "IsApprove": true
        }
        responses.push(response);
    }
    for(var ind =0; ind < deniedItems.length; ind++) {
        var response = {
            "ResponseID": deniedItems[ind],
            "IsApprove": false
        }
        responses.push(response);
    }
    resResponse["Responses"] = responses;
}

if(deniedReason) {
    resResponse["Reason"] = "deniedReason";
}
```

Comment: This is actually the only way to do it in IE, being that IE does not appreciate forEach. Also...I am going to update your code a little

Answer (score 3):

What about

```js
var approvedItems = [2051, 2567];
    var deniedItems = [2053, 2569];
var deniedReason = "Naughty";

var result={
           Responses:[],
           "Reason":deniedReason
           }
approvedItems.forEach(a =>{result.Responses.push({
    "ResponseID": a,
    "IsApprove": true
   })})

 deniedItems.forEach(d =>{result.Responses.push({
    "ResponseID": d,
    "IsApprove": false
   })})
   
   console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!